# Global NavOptions for the entire application

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to change the navCtrl animation for my entire app. Currently I have this call for every button:

```
this.navCtrl.push(Page2, {}, {animate: false});
```

Is there any way to do it globally and avoid applying it on each button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the animation for the full app from app.module.ts by editing imports section

```
 imports: [
        ...
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
            animate: false // disable animation
        }),
        ...
]
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you!